# Haskell and webframeworks

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-snap-framework, happstack

I started developing an application (some boring accounting software for inhouse use) and decided to make it web-based as this would solve a couple of problems in one go.

Now with a couple of webframeworks for Haskell to choose from (happstack, yesod and snap) I still begin feeling the pain again of having to deal with HTML, CSS and devishly clever wired JavaScript.

Uhm.

So what the hell I thought might as well try going all the AJAX way and do the UI in either [Cappuccino](http://www.cappuccino-project.org/) or [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com). (SEO is not an issue here).

But now I wouldn't really need a full blown web-framework such as one of the three above, an HTTP server which could serve data wrapped in JSON or XML should in theory be enough.

Would there now still be a point in using either one of those three?

And most of all how feasible is the approach?

Günther

Comment: I'm curious how your accounting application came along. I am writing some accounting applications in Haskell as well. I'll try to link to it here, once we post it to the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your question might be verging on "overly broad" here - so I guess it depends on your requirements. You probably don't need things like type-safe URLs if all you are doing is exchanging JSON and in fact the Yesod book has a [JSON web service example](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/json-web-service) which avoids using Yesod itself and instead builds on the underlying [WAI](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai) package.

I can't comment on Snap and Happstack since I haven't really looked into them much, but there are other options too. For example [Scotty](https://github.com/xich/scotty) adds a simpler layer on top of WAI which should be more than adequate for building a basic server without much of a learning curve. I also found reading Scotty's code was a good way to build an understanding of WAI which is also very useful if you are developing more complicated Yesod apps.

Comment: Hi Luke, guilty as charged with being overly broad. Going this way, ie. using the server for merely for JSON and XML and no UI is my first attempt and I thus was also seeking reassurance.

Answer (score 2):

All of the big three web frameworks have their own web servers.  Yesod's server is [warp](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp).  Snap's server is [snap-server](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-server).  Happstack's server is [happstack-server](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-server).  They all have fairly low level APIs that would be appropriate for your application.  Warp's API is defined in [wai](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai).  The Snap server's API is defined in [snap-core](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core).  Happstack doesn't have a separate package for its API, however they have a simplified version of it in the [happstack-lite](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-lite) package.

I would recommend that you take a look at the APIs and use whichever one you like best.